# PHP-Formatting table header

Tags: php, csv

This code reads a CSV file for creating a table. It works fine.

How do I make the 1st row to be formatted in header style (from the table CSS)?

```
<table  id="myTable" class="tablesorter animated fadeInDown">    <!--   cellspacing='0' is important, must stay -->

 <tbody>
    <?php
      $lines = file('graphdata/IndicForTableVsOthers.csv');  


      foreach ($lines as $lineNum => $line) {
    if($lineNum == 0) {
     print "     <tr id=\"tr" . $lineNum . "\">";
    }
        print "     <tr id=\"tr" . $lineNum . "\">";

        $tokens = str_getcsv($line);          

        print "<td style=\"width: 300px;\">" . trim($tokens[0]) . "</td>";      
        print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[1]) . "</td>";  
        print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[2]) . "</td>";
        print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[3]) . "</td>";
        print "<td style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[4]) . "</td>";


        print "</script>\n";

      }
    ?>

    </tbody>
```

Comment: Do you have the table headers inside the CSV File? you mean, you want to be the very first row of the CSV to be the column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, I also changed some other parts who I think would have generated wrong marup.

```
<table  id="myTable" class="tablesorter animated fadeInDown">

    <?php
    $lines = file('graphdata/IndicForTableVsOthers.csv');  

    foreach ($lines as $lineNum => $line) {
        $cellType = ($lineNum == 0 ? "th" : "td");
        $tokens = str_getcsv($line);

        if ($lineNum == 0) echo "<thead>";
        if ($lineNum == 1) echo "<tbody>";

        echo "<tr id=\"tr" . $lineNum . "\">";

        echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 300px;\">" . trim($tokens[0]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
        echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[1]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
        echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[2]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
        echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[3]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";
        echo "<" . $cellType . " style=\"width: 100px;\">" . trim($tokens[4]) . "</" . $cellType . ">";

        echo "</tr>";

        if ($lineNum == 0) echo "</thead>";
    }

    if (count($lines) > 1) echo "</tbody>";
    ?>

</table>
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like that, but let's notice that he's printing all inside a <tbody> tag, and the <th> tag should be inside <thead>

Comment: Thank you, @JuanBonnett, I corrected it and also found some other mistakes (for example the closing tag of the cells). I didn't test the code, let me know if it is not yet working for you.

Comment: Makes more sense now, I don't see why It shouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

If the first row is printed but it looks light and you want it Bold and Pretty so the user knows it's the header, add a class for convenience.

```
table.cs-contents tr:first-child td {
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #eaeaea;
}
```